# Access violation in delphi-7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

OK i'm writing an educational program that uses different forms. This is the first time i'm coding with multiple form as i'm still a novice programmer.

when my "sign in" button is clicked it opens the new form but then displays an access violation code.

```
    unit SignInNew_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, xpman;

type
TSignInNew = class(TForm)
Panel1: TPanel;
Label2: TLabel;
Label3: TLabel;
Label1: TLabel;
Label4: TLabel;
edtName: TEdit;
edtSurname: TEdit;
btnSignIn: TButton;
help: TButton;
procedure btnSignInClick(Sender: TObject);
procedure helpClick(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
  SignInNew: TSignInNew;
implementation

uses HelpNew_u, ElementsNew;

{$R *.dfm}

 procedure TSignInNew.btnSignInClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
 sName,sSurname,text:string;
 User:TextFile;
 begin

ElementsNew.TMain.Create(self);
ElementsNew.Main.Show;
Main.WindowState:= wsMaximized;

end;
procedure TSignInNew.helpClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
HelpNew := THelpNew.Create(self);
HelpNew.Show;
HelpNew.Width:=281;
HelpNew.Height:=481;
end;

end.
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRQeB.png)

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show an [mcve], so that we don't need to guess. Please don't delete questions and ask new ones. Edit questions to improve them. Do it your way and you lose the comments. You simply have to slow down and learn to do this properly.

Comment: Follow the link in my comment and all will be well

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `ElementsNew.TMain` and `HelpNew` are the name of the forms i used. I don't have the same problem with `HelpNew`. I did struggle in the beginning  and also had access violations but fixed it by simply `HelpNew := THelpNew.Create(self);`.

Comment: Yes but we can't see all of the code. I guessed the same as Agustin, I'm sure all the answerers did. But we could not be sure. What we can be sure of is that these public global variables are a nightmare. The IDE has tricked you. Delete these global variables. You don't need them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking your code, you are instantiating a class (TMain)

```
ElementsNew.TMain.Create(self);
```

but never assigning it to a variable. You are using a nil var (Main)

```
ElementsNew.Main.Show;
Main.WindowState:= wsMaximized;
```

To solve this:

```
Main := ElementsNew.TMain.Create(self);
Main.Show;
```

Comment: But you don't want to do this. You don't want to use global variables in that way.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I just say how to solve the problem